# Android BroadcastReceiver on BOOT_COMPLETED does not start alarm

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, bootcompleted

I'm trying to use a relatively simple solution to execute some code on boot. Basically I want to schedule/reschedule an Alarm at boot to execute a certain task in the future.

In my manifest I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<receiver android:name="com.cswt.lcyairport.alarm.AlarmReceiver">
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And my code:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.context = context;

    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)) {

        // Setup alarm
        scheduleAlarm();

        //Intent pushIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class); 
        //pushIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        //context.startActivity(pushIntent);

    }

}

private void scheduleAlarm() {
    long interval = 10*1000;

    Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(AlarmReceiver.ACTION_GO_TO_GATE);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)       context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 10000, interval, pendingIntent);
}
```

If I uncomment the code to start the activity it works great, and I see BOOT_COMPLETED is captured by my receiver. However, trying to start the alarm does not work (also tried showing a notification and it doesn't work).
How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you register your receiver.

Comment: Apparently I don't need... and if I want to open an activity it works.

Comment: did you register a broadcastreceiver for AlarmReceiver.ACTION_GO_TO_GATE ? on if so, did you do it in the manifest ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use different request Code and save them somewhere to use again after device reboots.You have to use the same request Code that you have used to set your Alarm with PendingIntent. Then it will work after reboot. And also you have to make sure that request Code isn't used again because Say you set an Alarm with a request Code 0 wit.h PendingIntent, then if you set another Alarm request Code 0 then your previous Alarm will be replaced by the newer one. So, you'll not get the first Alarm.

Edit:
Set alarm with the following snippet

```
public void SetAlarm(Calendar calendar, int reqCode) { 

 String dateName = idea.getText().toString(); String dateNote = 
 note.getText().toString(); Log.d("SetAlarm Texts", "Date : " + dateName + " 
 Note: " + dateNote);

Intent myIntent = new Intent(mActivity, AlarmReceiver.class);

myIntent.putExtra("title", "Her : " + dateName);

myIntent.putExtra("notes", dateNote);

myIntent.putExtra("code", reqCode);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mActi vity, reqCode, myIntent, 0); 

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_ SERVICE);

alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RT C, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to make sense. On boot I'm setting an alarm, so I'm not repeating request codes here.

Comment: Set alarms through a service . Use the code snippet to set alarm.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use flag FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT while creating pending intent using either getService, getActivity or getBroadCast.so that it keeps the current pending intent.it wont replace it.please reffer this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT?

```
Intent in = new Intent(arg0, Myservice.class);
PendingIntent pin = PendingIntent.getService(arg0, 0, in,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) arg0.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(arg0.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 30 * 1000, pin);
```

Answer (score 0):

have you added the necessary permission to your manifest ? ?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Comment: Second line of my post.

Comment: sorry, missed that one. could you add the code for your broadcast receiver which should act on AlarmReceiver.ACTION_GO_TO_GATE ?